# How can a plane fly far longer than designed?

Tags: commercial-operations, range

The current record for [longest commercial flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_distance_record#Commercial_aircraft) is 21,602.22km by Boeing 777-200LR.

However the designed maximum range for B777-200LR is [15,800 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#Specifications). So how is this possible?

Comment: You may find [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/how-do-airliners-get-from-the-factory-to-the-client-if-the-aircraft-does-not-hav), or better the answers below it, helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design range is fully loaded.  This flight had 35 passengers, no cargo, full fuel and was run as a project and flown by a test pilot.  It was not a commercial flight in the meaning that most people would recognise.

They had to wait for weeks until the winds aloft, especially the jet stream, were at their most advantageous.

Comment: and they used higher-density fuel. See [here](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a178559.pdf) (PDF) for specs.

Answer (score 0):

The designed maximum range is just a number, it is affected by a number of constrained factor like fuels and payload as wells as unconstrained factor like jet-steam.

[image]