# How do small planes cross oceans?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-manufacturer, transatlantic

I've often flown short flights around the US on aircraft built by non-American companies whose range is less than is required to make a traditional Atlantic crossing.  The Airbus A319-100, for instance, [has a range of 2,400 miles](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/airports-and-aircraft/Aircraft/airbus-a319-100.html) while the distance [from London to NYC is 3,440 miles](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=distance+from+heathrow+to+jfk).

How do manufacturers get their small planes across oceans?  Do they operate factories in on all continents? Do they fly via Iceland or Greenland?

Comment: The actual duplicate is [How do airliners get from the factory to the client if the aircraft does not have the required range](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3367/19)

Comment: @DeltaLima Actually, in this case, it _does_ have the required range. You just make a fuel stop in Iceland. Also, with the A320 family, your plane might not actually be coming from France, but rather [from Alabama](http://www.airbus.com/presscentre/pressreleases/press-release-detail/detail/airbus-officially-opens-us-manufacturing-facility/).

Comment: @Reirab Isn't the fuelstop in Iceland a result of the lack of range to reach the customer? Anyway, the A320 can reach the USA directly from the factory in Hamburg or Toulouse, albeit on fumes. The [BA1 A318](http://www.flightradar24.com/BAW1) service from London City airport to New York makes a fuel stop in Shannon (Ireland), but takes 32 business class passengers with it and crosses on a daily basis.

Comment: @DeltaLima I was taking "doesn't have the required range" in the linked question to mean "the route contains at least one leg that the aircraft cannot fly with its normal range," like in the case of the Hawaiian Airlines 717s mentioned in the first answer. You're right, though, that the A320 family does normally have more range than what the OP linked for the Delta A319s. Wiki lists the A318 at 3,100 nmi at MTOW (though that's still just barely enough for BA1, especially going against the wind towards the U.S.; I'd assume it flies at least somewhat light.)