# How does Boeing Deliver single aisle jets to South east Asia?

Tags: jet, boeing-737

I am not sure if they can fly on full tank gas to their destination (say India or Thailand), but how does Boeing deliver single aisle jets to these destinations. I read somewhere about the process of delivery, but I am more interested to know what kind of skip hop flights do they take for delivery? Any way we can track new outgoing aircraft?

Comment: [Also related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3367/62)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic. More specifically, science.

Even regional aircraft are generally designed with 3,500+ nmi range with some load, and more without. It's more than enough to travel to anywhere in the world, given some refueling stops.

In fact, even WWII combat aircraft, which had a fraction of modern airliner range (though it took a big dip once we went from props to jets), were able to travel to both Europe and Japan for duty.

Comment: They ferry them out there, same as any other aircraft.  The plane can be fitted with ferry tanks inside the lower baggage area to increase the range as needed for the flight or multiple stops may be made.